# How to set a template for two factor authentication emails in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have created HTML templates that I use to send emails to the users. These templates are pure HTML, not a razor. So I use an awaitable method to read the template:

```
public static async Task<string> ReadTemplate(string emailTemplate)
{
    var template = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, emailTemplate);

    string body;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(template))
    {
        body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    return body;
}
```

Then I replace some values in there before sending it out. Now I need to do the same thing for sending the security code when the user has activated the two factor authentication.

The message format for the 2FA code is in the `IdentityConfig.cs` in the `ApplicationUserManager` method. It is the bit that says:

```
manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
{
    Subject = "Security Code",
    BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
});
```

How can I set the template for this email? Can somebody please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find an elegant solution. However, solved it by doing a check on the message body and if it was saying "Your security code is ", then I injected my HTML template.